# lint-staged prettier write doesn't end

Tags: reactjs, prettier, husky, lint-staged

I am using Husky and lint-staged in a React (TypeScript) project.
My files look like this:

`package.json`

```
    "check-types": "tsc --pretty --noEmit",
    "fix-eslint:staged": "yarn check-eslint:staged --fix",
    "fix-format:staged": "prettier --write",
```

`pre-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

yarn lint-staged
```

`lint-staged.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}': () => [
    'yarn check-types',
    'yarn fix-eslint:staged',
    'yarn fix-format:staged'
  ],
  '**/*.css': ['yarn fix-stylelint:css']
};
```

The problem is the prettier script `yarn fix-format:staged` never ends. It keeps on going, even if I place it at the top.

[image]

If I move the lint-stage settings to `package.json` like below, then the `yarn check-types` fails with error: `Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.`

`package.json`

```
"lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "yarn check-types",
      "yarn fix-eslint:staged",
      "yarn fix-format:staged"
    ],
    "**/*.css": [
      "yarn fix-stylelint:css"
    ]
  },
```

Can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

on pre-commit use :

```
npx lint-staged
```